# How to make the curve of a function smoother?

Tags: pgfplots

I am preparing a document for undergraduate student in Persian. Somewhere I need to study the function $x*\sin(1/x)$. Since using a picture made by Maple:

[image]

in the body is somehow unclear figure, so I was going to do it by Latex. This is what I can get from the net:

> ```
> \documentclass{standalone} 
>    \usepackage{pgfplots} 
>    \begin{document} 
>    \begin{tikzpicture} 
>    \begin{axis}
>    \addplot[color=red]{x*sin(1/x)};
>    \end{axis}
>    \end{tikzpicture}
>    \end{document}
> ```

The axis, ranges and non smooth curve made me upset:

[image]

May I ask you to make light on it? Thanks for the time!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

like this?

[image]

define more samples, for example add to `\addplot` options `samples=300` and restrict function domain to sensible range:

```
\documentclass[margin=3mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.15}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}
\addplot[color=red, domain=-0.05:0.05, samples=600]{x*sin(1/x)};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

**addendum:**
in form more similar to image generated by maple:

[image]

```
\documentclass[margin=3mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.15}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
xmin=-0.05, xmax=0.05,
scaled ticks=false,
/pgf/number format/fixed,
axis x line=center,
axis y line=center,
xlabel=$x$,
ylabel=$x\sin(1/x)$
            ]
\addplot[color=red, domain=-0.05:0.05, samples=3000]{x*sin(1/x)};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks again for your nice answer. Indeed, what I wanted is the second. Now, I am free to manage the tex file. :-)